# Xamarin - Setting Camera feed as background

Tags: android, xamarin, camera, xamarin.android, textureview

So, I'm trying to make a login activity with the camera feed as the background. I've tested the example on https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/textureview/ and got it to work, but I need to it to be part of an activity. So, I tried this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login);

        _textureView = this.FindViewById<TextureView>(Resource.Id.textureView);
        _textureView.SurfaceTextureListener = this;
    }

public void OnSurfaceTextureAvailable(
       Android.Graphics.SurfaceTexture surface, int w, int h)
        {
            _cam = Camera.Open();

            _textureView.LayoutParameters =
                   new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(w, h);

            try
            {
                _cam.SetPreviewTexture(surface);
                _cam.StartPreview();

            }
            catch (Java.IO.IOException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The axml file looks somewhat like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/textureView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional">

        <!-- Some other controls -->
    </LinearLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

However, the app now crashes after exiting the OnSurfaceTextureAvailable block, giving an unhandled exception. Breaking at the exception doesn't work, it's apparently in a thread that's not running anymore.
Would anyone know why it crashes and, more importantly, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with this code:

```
_textureView.LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(w, h);
```

I'm not sure why your need to reset the `TextureView`'s layout parameters, in xml you've set it to match parent. And the parent here is `AbsoluteLayout`, not `FrameLayout`, that's why this error happens.

To solve this issue, since `AbsoluteLayout` is obsolete now, I suggest to use `RelativeLayout` as root container in your xml. Then you can code like this:

```
_textureView.LayoutParameters = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
```

Of course you can also change `AbsoluteLayout` to `FrameLayout` in your xml, then the code `_textureView.LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(w, h);` doesn't need to be modified anymore.

Comment: Ah, simply taking that line out has fixed the error, and it's now showing a camera feed as I intended, many thanks. There's a different problem now, but I'll open another question for that since it's unrelated to this error.